# How to create a shortcut for widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created the widget, but this widget does not show directly on the home screen, I want it to be displayed directly on the home screen, immediately after the application is deployed, like a shortcut, and clicking on the shortcut widget will go to the application

Can someone suggest me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be displayed directly on the home screen, immediately after the application is deployed

You cannot run any code at the time the user installs your application. You must wait for them to launch it, or in the case of a home screen widget you must wait for them to explicitly place it on the home screen.

Comment: I want to be when the widget is created, it will show up directly on the homescreen that does not need to add it to the homescreen

Comment: you have to wait for the user to add it...You cannot do that yourself.

Comment: widget can display as a shortcut is not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an intent line to your manifest that exposes the action you want to do through a shortcut.

see: http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html?m=1

Comment: widget can display as a shortcut is not?